# Wordpress retrieving data from Cakephp

Tags: wordpress, cakephp

I run a website where I have both Wordpress and Cakephp installed in the **same domain.**

Cakephp is the administrative backend to maintain and create business listings (like the yellow pages).

Wordpress is the front end for the public website.

I'm creating custom Wordpress templates to display the business listings from Cakephp, but am not sure how Wordpress is going to retrieve data from Cakephp.

I already have a bunch of Controller Actions that return json array with data that I would like to call from Wordpress. I don't want to duplicate in Wordpress data retrieval code that I've already written in Cakephp. But i'm not sure how in Wordpres would i make calls to these Cakephp Controller / Actions.

What is the **recommended / best way to have Wordpress retrieve data from the Cakephp** backend given at they are on the same domain? What other options do i have?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the recommended / best way to have Wordpress retrieve data
>   from the Cakephp backend given at they are on the same domain? What
>   other options do i have?

Access the DB directly, I'm not sure how to do that with Wordpress fugly API and code, but I'm pretty sure you can instantiate a new DB object with a connection to the CakePHP apps database. The WP API documentation will tell you how to do it I guess, if not it sucks more than I thought.

An alternative would be to expose the data via a [RESTful service](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html) and consume it from Wordpress. If you return JSON you could even simply use a JS widget on a WP page to retrieve and render the data with pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

As burzum suggested you have 2 real options.

WordPress does have a class for interacting with a DB called WPDB and will give you access to a few ways of querying the data in your CakePHP app. [WordPress WPDB Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). It is by no means perfect but will do the job.

However you much better creating a custom WordPress plugin to parse and format the JSON as burzum suggested interacting via your own API. You could then if needed make this a 2 way communication allowing your WordPress install to make changes as necessary to yoru Cake app.